# Positive Semi Definite (PSD) matrix with perturbation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-semidefinite

By the definition of PSD matrix, given a vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, I know that $x^T A x \geq 0$ if $A$ is PSD. I am curious that if I add a perturbation on one $x$ such that $\|x + d\| < \varepsilon$, can I establish some statement (related to $d$) that $x^T A (x + d)$ still have positive number? Any insights would be helpful.

Comment: I wonder if you meant $\|d\|<\varepsilon$ (so that $x+d$ is close to $x$) rather than $\|x+d\|<\varepsilon. \qquad$

Comment: Note that 
$$
x^TA(x+d) = x^TAx + x^TAd \geq x^TAx - |x^TAd| \geq x^TAx - \|A^Tx\| \cdot \|d\|.
$$